# How to covert object literal AST of TypeScript file to Actual Code?

Tags: typescript, babeljs, abstract-syntax-tree, babylonjs, transpiler

I need to convert a JSON or Object Literal file to actual code. How to do it?

```js
const astInJson = {"pos":0,"end":79,"flags":0,"kind":268,"text":"export interface Order {\n\torderId: string;\n\titineraries(id: string): string;\n}\n","bindDiagnostics":[],"languageVersion":5,"fileName":"/Users/myth/Desktop/test-interface.ts","languageVariant":0,"isDeclarationFile":false,"scriptKind":3,"referencedFiles":[],"typeReferenceDirectives":[],"amdDependencies":[],"statements":[{"pos":0,"end":78,"flags":0,"kind":230,"modifiers":[{"pos":0,"end":6,"flags":0,"kind":84}],"name":{"pos":16,"end":22,"flags":0,"escapedText":"Order"},"members":[{"pos":24,"end":42,"flags":0,"kind":148,"name":{"pos":24,"end":33,"flags":0,"escapedText":"orderId"},"type":{"pos":34,"end":41,"flags":0,"kind":136}},{"pos":42,"end":76,"flags":0,"kind":150,"name":{"pos":42,"end":55,"flags":0,"escapedText":"itineraries"},"parameters":[{"pos":56,"end":66,"flags":0,"kind":146,"name":{"pos":56,"end":58,"flags":0,"escapedText":"id"},"type":{"pos":59,"end":66,"flags":0,"kind":136}}],"type":{"pos":68,"end":75,"flags":0,"kind":136}}],"modifierFlagsCache":536870913}],"endOfFileToken":{"pos":78,"end":79,"flags":0,"kind":1},"externalModuleIndicator":{"pos":0,"end":78,"flags":0,"kind":230,"modifiers":[{"pos":0,"end":6,"flags":0,"kind":84}],"name":{"pos":16,"end":22,"flags":0,"escapedText":"Order"},"members":[{"pos":24,"end":42,"flags":0,"kind":148,"name":{"pos":24,"end":33,"flags":0,"escapedText":"orderId"},"type":{"pos":34,"end":41,"flags":0,"kind":136}},{"pos":42,"end":76,"flags":0,"kind":150,"name":{"pos":42,"end":55,"flags":0,"escapedText":"itineraries"},"parameters":[{"pos":56,"end":66,"flags":0,"kind":146,"name":{"pos":56,"end":58,"flags":0,"escapedText":"id"},"type":{"pos":59,"end":66,"flags":0,"kind":136}}],"type":{"pos":68,"end":75,"flags":0,"kind":136}}],"modifierFlagsCache":536870913},"nodeCount":15,"identifierCount":5,"identifiers":{},"parseDiagnostics":[]}
```

Comment: At least in this case, it looks like the outermost `text` property has the source code.  Do you want the source code or do you want to load the code as a module object in the current JavaScript runtime?

Comment: @MattMcCutchen Yes in text property it's present. But I don't want to use that. I want to change few property in the object literal and it should give me data as Typescript source code. In short I need JSON to Typescript.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `ts.SourceFile` object, you can use:

```
ts.createPrinter().printFile(file)
```

which returns a string.  `ts.SourceFile` is a data structure that contains cyclic references; if you have some subset of the fields as JSON, I don't know if there's any reasonable way to convert that back to a `ts.SourceFile`.  For more ideas, you could look at [the API to modify and print ASTs that is used by TypeScript's own code fixes](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/src/services/textChanges.ts).